# How to update 2 rows in mysql with one update?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data

How can I update with one query?
I want to do something like this:

```
update customer 
set balance = (400,150)  where customer_id IN ('2','3');
```

customer 2 will get a new balance of 400 and customer 3 will get 150.

I want 1 query because I'm using spring-boot, JPA

```
@Modifying
@Query("update customer set balance = (400,150)  where customer_id IN ('2','3');")
```

Can I do here 2 queries? for each customer?
what is recommended? what is acceptable?

thanks.

Comment: Now if only Hibernate could do that for you... Enable batch processing for both Hibernate and MySQL, write your code as usual and Hibernate will rewrite the statement to a single batch statement. Nothing you, apart for the configuration, have to do for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do by this way -

```
Update customer
   SET balance = (case when customer_id = '2' then '400'
                         when customer_id = '3' then '150'
                    end)
  WHERE
   customer_id IN ('2','3');
```

Answer (score 0):

The CASE statement may be what you are looking for.

```sql
UPDATE customer
    SET balance = (case
                    when customer_id = 1 then 150
                    when customer_id = 2 then 300
                    end)        
    WHERE ID in (1,2);
```

If your customer_id is of type string, add quotes to the customer_id numbers.

My example is just a modified version of:

```sql
Example Code:

UPDATE students
    SET JavaScore = (case
                    when ID = 1 then 75
                    when ID = 2 then 80
                    when ID = 3 then 86
                    when ID = 4 then 55
                    end),
        PythonScore = (case
                    when ID = 1 then 70
                    when ID = 2 then 85
                    when ID = 3 then 94
                    when ID = 4 then 75
                    end)
    WHERE ID in (1,2,3,4);
```

From this website:

[DelftStack](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/mysql/update-multiple-columns-in-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the spring-data way, you have to use complex SQL/JPQL as less as possible.

```java
@Entity
class CustomerEntity {

}

@Modifying
@Query("update CustomerEntity customer set customer.balance = :balance where customer.id = :customerId")
int updateCustomerBalance(@Param("customerId") String customerId, @Param("balance") String balance);

customerRepository.updateCustomerBalance("2", "400");
customerRepository.updateCustomerBalance("3", "150");
```

**Common transaction**

if you want to update happens in one transaction

```java
@Transactional
void doUpdate() {
    customerRepository.updateCustomerBalance("2", "400");
    customerRepository.updateCustomerBalance("3", "150");
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to call `service.doUpdate()` from outside. if you call the method from another service method, transaction will not be created.

**Check that update has happened**

```java
int count = customerRepository.updateCustomerBalance("2", "400");
if (count == 0) {
    log.error("Customer not updated customerId=2 customerBalance=400");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate can do this for you, no need to write your own query.

The steps.

1. Set `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to some reasonable size.
2. Enable insert/update query ordering
3. Enable statement rewrites for MySQL (set `rewriteBatchedStatements` to `true`)

In your application.properties add the following

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true # Needed when using versioned data
spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourcePoperties.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

See also [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/) and [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/mysql-rewritebatchedstatements/) for a bit more background.

Now in your code you can just update and save your customers and the database will receive only 1 query.